# DualHashBidiMap and getKey method

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have an issue with the DualHashBidiMap and getKey method.

I'm using Commons Collections 4.1

The *containsKey* method returns true for specific key insterted, but *getKey* method returns null for the same key;

Key Class have a SuperClass with *equals* and *hashcode* method overrided to match by *id* property.

---

Main Class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DualHashBidiMap<Observed, Object> map=new DualHashBidiMap<Observed,Object>();

    Task t66=new Task();
    t66.setId(66);
    map.put(t66, "Task66");

    Task tFetch=new Task();
    tFetch.setId(66);
    System.out.println("tFetch present:"+map.containsKey(tFetch));
    System.out.println("tFetch Object:"+map.getKey(tFetch));
   }
}
```

this is the output

```
tFetch present:true
tFetch Object:null
```

Key Class

```
public class Task extends Observed{

public void m1(){
    System.out.println("Method called !!");
  }
}
```

Key SuperClass

```
public class Observed extends Observable{
private Integer id;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean retValue=false;
    Observed t=(Observed) obj;
    if(t.getId().equals(this.getId())) retValue=true;
    return retValue;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + (this.getId() != null ? this.getId().hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 53 * hash + this.getId();
    return hash;
   }
}
```

Tnks to all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get key for a value that doesn't exist in the map. May be you want to do as below

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DualHashBidiMap<Observed, Object> map=new DualHashBidiMap<Observed,Object>();

    Task t66=new Task();
    t66.setId(66);
    map.put(t66, "Task66");

    Task tFetch=new Task();
    tFetch.setId(66);
    System.out.println("tFetch present:"+map.containsKey(tFetch));
    // to get the key related to an object
    System.out.println("tFetch Object:"+map.getKey("Task66"));
    // to get a value related to a key
    System.out.println("tFetch Object:"+map.get(tFetch));
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now i understood. I thought that getKey method returned Key Object by key value. Sorry for the mistake and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If this answers your question, then mark it as the answered so that other unanswered questions get the attention needed